# Play widevine content located in App Documents iOS

Tags: ios, playback, drm, widevine

I am trying to playback a wvm file that I download through an iOS app and located in the apps document directory. I am getting a 1013 error and I believe this is due to the files location and the WideVine api not having access to that location. Any ideas on how to overcome this? Or am I wrong and the issue is something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this issue to be with the File URL starting with File://

Once I removed that it all worked great.

Comment: I use local path to file in document directory, but still got 1013 on WV_RegisterAsset. What else could be a problem?

Comment: You get this error when it is unable to find the file. So make sure that you are giving it the full correct path.