# Play downloaded Widevine Classic files from app document folder in iOS?

Tags: ios, widevine

I am trying to play wvm files from the app documents folder since 3 days but without success...

I removed "file://" from my path but I still get 1013 error ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221925/play-widevine-content-located-in-app-documents-ios/37005343)), does someone have some sample code or at least the procedure to follow to make it works properly?

`WV_RegisterAsset(myFilePath)` always return `WViOsApiStatus(rawValue: 1013)`

The file should exists because when I try this:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager()
print(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(myFilePath))
```

It returns **true**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widevine Classic on iOS uses an "asset root" directory. When you initialize the library, you pass it in the settings dictionary using the key WVAssetRootKey. 
After that, all local asset pathnames you pass to the library are relative to the AssetRoot.

One simple option is to use NSHomeDirectory() as the AssetRoot, and then trim it from the beginning of absolute pathnames.